# How do i Get profile photo of specific resolution using Microsoft graph sdk

Tags: microsoft-graph-sdks

How do I get profile pic of specific resolution using graph service client sdk ?
using below code I get profile pic of only one resolution i.e. 360* 360

```
graphServiceClient.Users["serviceprincipal"].Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync().Result
```

Thanks,

Comment: So what is "*graph service client sdk*", the tag is vague to the extreme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After R&D , found the answer

```
var graphServiceClient= new GraphServiceClient(
                      new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                         (requestMessage) =>
                         {
                             requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", response.access_token);
                             return Task.FromResult(0);
                         }));

graphServiceClient.Users["serviceprincipal"].Photos["64x64"].Content.Request().GetAsync().Result
```